# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void (***) on a null object reference

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am running into an issue where I get the error.

Process: ericscalise.cs499.bloodhoundcommunity, PID: 22247
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ericscalise.cs499.bloodhoundcommunity/ericscalise.cs499.bloodhoundcommunity.MyProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

I am not sure 100% what I am doing wrong. This section is to show my users firebase information back to them and I have the firebase setting all set correctly according to their docs and android studio. Below is the code from the activity that is throwing the error. and help would be appreciated.

```
package ericscalise.cs499.bloodhoundcommunity;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

//information and code received from smallAcademy github https://github.com/bikashthapa01/firebase-authentication-android
 
public class MyProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView fullName,email,phone,verifyMsg;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userId;
    Button resendCode;
    Button resetPassLocal,changeProfileImage;
    FirebaseUser user;
    ImageView profileImage;
    StorageReference storageReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final int GALLERY_INTENT_CODE = 1023 ;

        phone = findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        email    = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        resetPassLocal = findViewById(R.id.resetPasswordLocal);

        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        changeProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.changeProfile);


        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        StorageReference profileRef = storageReference.child("users/"+fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/profile.jpg");
        profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profileImage);
            }
        });


        verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyMsg);


        userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
            verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Verification Email Has been Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("tag", "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }




        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    phone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phone"));
                    fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                    email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));

                }else {
                    Log.d("tag", "onEvent: Document do not exists");
                }
            }
        });


        resetPassLocal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText resetPassword = new EditText(v.getContext());

                final AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Reset Password ?");
                passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Enter New Password > 6 Characters long.");
                passwordResetDialog.setView(resetPassword);

                passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // extract the email and send reset link
                        String newPassword = resetPassword.getText().toString();
                        user.updatePassword(newPassword).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "Password Reset Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "Password Reset Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // close
                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.create().show();

            }
        });

        changeProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open gallery
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),EditProfileActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("fullName",fullName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("email",email.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("phone",phone.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I figured out the answer after hours of review and driving myself crazy.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

should have been

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);
```